# Unable to video fullscreen dojotoolkit & html5

Tags: html, video, dojo, html5-video

I'm trying to get video to play fullscreen when orientation is changed to landscape.

I'm using dojotoolkit to detect orientation change:

```
on(window, "resize", lang.hitch(this, function(){
    if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {

    } else {
        dom.byId("player").webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}));
```

I have a simple video element with a source pointing to a server:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <video id="player" class="embed-responsive-item" preload controls>
            <source id="source" src="https://someservername.com?ksaofoasfoia.m4v"></source>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

On video controls I'm able to trigger fullscreen, but via my js code it's not working.

Not sure why its not working. Did I miss anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons you can't trigger the fullscreen request other than through a short lived user triggered event like a keypress or a click.

One way to deal with this situation is to use CSS e.g.

```
#player {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

or in your case replace :

```
dom.byId("player").webkitRequestFullScreen();
```

with this:

```
query("#player").style({idth: "100%", height: "100%"});
```

It's actually very similar to how the fullscreen api actually works in the first place. See the MDN docs on the subject for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Presentation_differences

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you cannot trigger a fullscreen event unless it is triggered by user.
I'm going to be looking at CSS solution to this issue.